# Cannot get access to the nfc instance in ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, nfc, cordova-plugins

I am trying to write nfc data using [phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/don/ionic-nfc-reader) plugin. Here is the `factory` I have:

```
.factory('nfcService', function ($rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {
  var tag = {};
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(function (nfcEvent) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(nfcEvent.tag, null, 4));
      $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        angular.copy(nfcEvent.tag, tag);
        // if necessary $state.go('some-route')
      });
    }, function () {
      console.log("Listening for tags.");
    }, function (reason) {
      alert("Error adding NFC Listener " + reason);
    });

    nfc.addMimeTypeListener('', function (nfcEvent) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(nfcEvent.tag, null, 4));
      $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        angular.copy(nfcEvent.tag, tag);
        // if necessary $state.go('some-route')
      });
    });
  });
  return {
    tag: tag,
    clearTag: function () {
      angular.copy({}, this.tag);
    }
  };
})
```

And here is my controller:

```
.controller('NfcCtrl', function($scope, nfcService){
    console.log('inside NfcCtrl');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(nfcService));
    nfcService.then(function(nfcInstance) {
        nfcInstance.write = function() {
            console.log('writing nfc...');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(nfcService));

            var message = [
                ndef.textRecord("hello, world"),
                ndef.uriRecord("http://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc")
            ];
            console.log('trying to write nfc message...');
            nfcService.write(message, function (success) {
               console.log("Wrote data to tag.");
            }, function (reason) {
               console.log("There was a problem " + reason);
            });
        };
    });
})
```

I've also included the required javascript file in the `index.html` file:

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova-nfc/nfc.js"></script>
```

The `NfcPlugin` initializes successfully, but I am getting the following error:

```
0     312690   log      Initialized the NfcPlugin
1     312825   log      inside NfcCtrl
2     312826   log      {"tag":{}}
3     312846   error    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'
    at new <anonymous> (http://192.168.1.105:8100/js/controllers.js:28:16)
    at Object.invoke (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
    at extend.instance (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22311:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21421:36)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20853:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21457:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20853:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20728:30)
    at self.appendViewElement (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56890:5)
    at Object.switcher.render (http://192.168.1.105:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54995:41), <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="android">
4     312894   log      Listening for tags.
```

How can I access the nfc object to call its `write` [method](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcwrite)?

Comment: #<Object> has no method 'then'
    at new <anonymous> (http://192.168.1.105:8100/js/controllers.js:28:16)
your nfcService factory does not return any promises which you can follow up with 'then'

Comment: @JuniorDev How can I return a promise from my factory?